# kotlin + Dagger 2: ApiService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have gone through all the answers with the above title but couldn't find the solution. Basically I want to do scoping. I want to inject ApiService only to `HomeViewModel`. It should not be available to `LoginViewModel`. I have my following setup and the error which I am getting:

**Info**: If I remove the `provideLoginActivity()` from `ActivityModule` everything works fine. Why behaving like that?

**AppComponent**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, ActivityModule::class, AppModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApplication> {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun application(@BindsInstance baseApplication: BaseApplication): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**AppModule**:

```
@Module
object AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

**ActivityModule**:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelBuilder::class, NetworkModule::class])
    internal abstract fun getHomeActivity(): HomeActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelBuilder::class])
    internal abstract fun provideLoginActivity(): LoginActivity

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindLoginViewModel(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(HomeViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindHomeViewModel(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

**NetworkModule**:

```
@Module
object NetworkModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun getApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }

}
```

**ViewModelFactory**:

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: @JvmSuppressWildcards Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]
        if (creator == null) {
            for ((key, value) in creators) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown model class: $modelClass")
        }
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}

@Module
internal abstract class ViewModelBuilder {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(
        factory: ViewModelFactory
    ): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}

@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

**HomeViewModel**:

```
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService) : ViewModel() {
    val todoLiveData: LiveData<Todo> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response: Todo = apiService.getTodo(1)
        emit(response)
    }
}
```

**Error**:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.sagar.daggertest.repository.network.ApiService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.sagar.daggertest.BaseApplication> {
                ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: com.sagar.daggertest.di.HomeActivityModule_GetHomeActivity$app_debug.HomeActivitySubcomponent
      com.sagar.daggertest.repository.network.ApiService is injected at
          com.sagar.daggertest.HomeViewModel(apiService)
      com.sagar.daggertest.HomeViewModel is injected at
          com.sagar.daggertest.di.HomeActivityModule.bindHomeViewModel(homeViewModel)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          com.sagar.daggertest.di.ViewModelFactory(creators)
      com.sagar.daggertest.di.ViewModelFactory is injected at
          com.sagar.daggertest.di.ViewModelBuilder.bindViewModelFactory$app_debug(factory)
      androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
          com.sagar.daggertest.LoginActivity.viewModelFactory
      com.sagar.daggertest.LoginActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.sagar.daggertest.di.AppComponent → com.sagar.daggertest.di.HomeActivityModule_ProvideLoginActivity$app_debug.LoginActivitySubcomponent]
```

Comment: Try adding @Singleton to getApiServiceMethod

Comment: Getting this error now:
`HomeActivitySubcomponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings`

Comment: Can you please post your HomeViewModel code

Comment: I have added some Info to the question. That might help to find the problem. @ShwetaChauhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ContributesAndroidInjector` creates a [subcomponent](https://dagger.dev/subcomponents.html) under the hood ( which is `HomeActivityModule_GetHomeActivity$app_debug.HomeActivitySubcomponent` in logs ).

In your `ActivityModule`, you're trying to provide `HomeViewModel` for map in `ViewModelFactory`, which is also injected at `LoginActivity`. But due to `HomeViewModel` needing `ApiService` and your `ApiService` is in `NetworkModule` which is scoped to subcomponent dagger generated - it fails.

Solution would be moving your multibinding to corresponding scope. By doing so, you're taking `HomeViewModel` out of map which is injected in `LoginActivity`, so it won't complain.

You can create a new module, let's say `ViewModelModule` and put your provider there:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(HomeViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindHomeViewModel(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

and pass it along with other modules to `HomeActivity`'s contributor:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelBuilder::class, NetworkModule::class, ViewModelModule::class])
internal abstract fun getHomeActivity(): HomeActivity
```

Comment: But If I remove the `provideLoginActivity()` everything works fine. Why is it behaving like that?

Comment: It's because of scoping issue. When you inject ViewModelBuilder to LoginActivity, it also tries to create HomeViewModel to pass it to ViewModelBuilder's map. But since LoginActivity's scope doesn't have ApiService, it fails. When you remove it, it only creates ViewModelBuilder for HomeActivity, which has ApiService, so it doesn't fail.

Comment: I don't want LoginViewModel to have access to `ApiService`. So basically it's a no.

Comment: If you move multibinding to HomeActivity's scope, then ViewModelBuilder won't try to create and inject HomeViewModel for LoginActivity, so it'll compile fine.

Comment: I'm updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: Should I move `LoginViewModel` also in the same `ViewModelModule`?

Comment: You can move it to it's own module. Catch here is - multibindings ( @Binds ) will collect everything on scope level and provide them. Whole point of ViewModelModule here is to separate LoginViewModel & HomeViewModel from being in same scope, so they don't get injected at same time.

Comment: Awesome! It's working. Thanks for this amazing help.

Comment: Any quick tip to how to learn Dagger 2 for android? I am just struggling to understand the internal work of these annotations.

Comment: You're welcome ! More you try this kind of things, more easier it will become, but I can't really suggest anything that would make things clear in an intant. They have a great documentation, going through it to understand what anything in library does is a good first step when struggling with something. Keep experimenting !

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that only. I am trying various stuff with Dagger 2 and then solving them if something went wrong. Thanks for the explanation.